# use one function array to other function in php

Tags: javascript, php

use one function array to other function  without returning the array like javascript

this code l'm converted js to php in js same code working perfect but in php return error
Undefined variable: const

```
$const = array();
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
readdata();  
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array) ; $i++) {
    $const[5]=$i;
    getall($array); 
}

function dependent($array,$tances) { 
    echo $index5 = $const[5];
    echo $index4 = $const[4];
    $index3 = $const[3]; 
    // $tances and $array for other purpose in this function
}

function getbid($array) { 
    $mid = 1.0;
    dependent($array,$mid); 
}

function getall($array) { 
    getbid($array);
}

function readdata() { 
    $latd=40;
    $latm=11;  
    $lond=44;
    $lonm=30;  
    $alt=0; 
    $tz=5; 
    $const[0]=$latd;
    $const[1]=$latm;
    $const[2]=$lond;
    $const[3]=$lonm;
    $const[4]=$tz; 
}
```

i'm converted js library to php maximum js function use those array to declare in the previous function.so i want to use the same code in PHP as it is

this js i'm converted into php 
in js all functions, arrays, and variables working perfect

```
var sconst= new Array();
var array= new Array(1,2); 
readdata();  

for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
    sconst[5]=i;
    getall(array); 
}

function dependent(array,mid) { 
    index5 = sconst[5]; 
    index4 = sconst[4];
    index3 = sconst[3];
    alert(index5+' '+index4+' '+index3)
    // $tances and $array for other purpose in this function
}

function getbid(array) { 
    var mid = 1.0;
    dependent(array,mid); 
}

function getall(array) { 
    getbid(array);
}

function readdata() { 
    var latd=40;
    var latm=11;  
    var lond=44;
    var lonm=30;  
    var alt=0; 
    var tz=5; 
    sconst[0]=latd;
    sconst[1]=latm;
    sconst[2]=lond;
    sconst[3]=lonm;
    sconst[4]=tz;  
}
```

Comment: In JS, the function `readdata()` can see `sconst` because `var` makes it visible to every block that is nested within the block where the variable was declared in. This is not true in PHP, therefore you should let `readdata()` return an array and assign it to `$const`.

Comment: sconst use in js and const use in php throughout all functions there is the variable accessing problem, not a variable name problem

Comment: You are not understanding my point. To “convert” from a programming language to another is not as simple as changing the syntax, you also have to take visibility, data types, and more into account. I’m not saying your problem is the name of the variables, your problem is not knowing why the variable is not accessible within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because `$const` doesn't exist in the scope of the `dependent` function. It also doesn't exist in the `readdata` function but you don't get an error there since you are not trying to read a value from it. You can resolve this most easily by adding `global $const;` to the `dependent` and `readdata` functions e.g.

```
function dependent($array,$tances) { 
    global $const;
    echo $index5 = $const[5] . "\n";
    echo $index4 = $const[4] . "\n";
    $index3 = $const[3]; 
    // $tances and $array for other purpose in this function
}
function readdata() { 
    global $const;
    $latd=40;
    $latm=11;  
    $lond=44;
    $lonm=30;  
    $alt=0; 
    $tz=5; 
    $const[0]=$latd;
    $const[1]=$latm;
    $const[2]=$lond;
    $const[3]=$lonm;
    $const[4]=$tz; 
}
```

Alternatively you need to modify your function calls to pass `$const` as a parameter (and return it as a value from `readdata`) i.e.

```
$const=array();
$array=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$const = readdata();  
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array) ; $i++) {
    $const[5]=$i;
    getall($const, $array); 
}
function dependent($const, $array, $tances) { 
    echo $index5 = $const[5] . "\n";
    echo $index4 = $const[4] . "\n";
    $index3 = $const[3]; 
    // $tances and $array for other purpose in this function
}
function getbid($const, $array) { 
    $mid = 1.0;
    dependent($const, $array, $mid); 
}
function getall($const, $array) { 
    getbid($const, $array);
}
function readdata() { 
    $latd=40;
    $latm=11;  
    $lond=44;
    $lonm=30;  
    $alt=0; 
    $tz=5; 
    $const[0]=$latd;
    $const[1]=$latm;
    $const[2]=$lond;
    $const[3]=$lonm;
    $const[4]=$tz; 
    return $const;
}
```

Comment: the first method return Undefined offset: 2-second method  in the functions and variables have multiple relations as above it's too difficult to pass a variable into multiple functions

Comment: @M.Javid I have the first version working in a demo https://3v4l.org/UfSrL

Comment: o yes but i'm used your demo code return error Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 5

Filename: views/ads.php

Line Number: 49

Comment: That must be in some code you didn't post in the question?

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend using the `global` keyword, but yeah, this is it. This answer should make it work.

Comment: @Zeke apparently not based on OPs comments with an error on a line that doesn't exist in his post (line 49 out of approximately 35)

Comment: @M.Javid if you're not happy with the answer please don't mark it accepted... I'm happy to help you find the correct solution if this isn't working.

Comment: @Nick I understand what you mean. I think you answered the question, that’s why I believe this is good enough. Another problem arose, but that doesn’t mean that this answer is wrong. Anyway, if it was marked accepted and no further comments were added, I’d guess those external issues were solved. Still, it’s true this shouldn’t be marked accepted until all issues are corrected and I get it.